# Audio/Sound Not Working

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

So a while back, I was using my computer to listen to music when suddenly a loud scratching noise came from the speakers. My sound worked after that but scratching still came occasionally.

However, later my audio completely stopped working. Spotify couldn't play songs.

So far I tried:

- updating the software,
- unplugging/plugging in my headphones, and no output devices have been found (see picture).
- reseting PRAM and still nothing.

Currently, whenever I try to change the volume, an error mark appears. I am wondering if the hardware is starting to become corrupt because my computer seems to slow down occasionally. I have gone through multiple troubleshooting and nothing seems to work.

Any answers? Should I take my computer to the Apple Store to fix it?

[image]

Comment: It does seem like a hardware problem, probably with the audio chip or surrounding circuitry. If it was a speaker problem the Mac would still "see" sound hardware in the Sound pref.pane.
Try running hardware diagnostics (CMD-D at boot) to diagnose. And tell us the model/year of your Mac for more specific advice.